# JavaScript - replace nth index of regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Suppose I have a regex expression in Javascript, how can I use the replace function to only replace the nth index of regex pattern.

For example suppose this is the target string:

```
var string = `if ($exampl123 == 'test13')
            $example = 'test.testeg.hi';
        
            if ($exampl123 == 'test23')
            $example = 'test.testeg.hi';`
```

The following expression matches the 'test.testeg.hi' part of the string (Matches the two spots where this string is visible).

`var deriveString = new RegExp (/test\.\w+\.hi';(?!.*test\.\w+\.hi';)/gm);`

In this situation, I would only want to replace the last occurence of this string. If I use the `string.prototype.match` function, It returns an array of all the matches which is `['test.testeg.hi' , 'test.testeg.hi']`

In this case, I would want to only replace the second occurrence of the pattern.

Is there anyway to use the javascript replace function to only replace the last occurrence of the pattern?

Something that allows some sort of way to access the index of the match to replace?
Something like this?

`string = string.replace(deriveString[matchedArray.length - 1] , 'insert new text here'`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should then remove the `g` option from your regex, and aim directly for the final match. This you can do with a greedy `(.*)` in front of it, and then reproduce that (long) prefix again in the replacement -- using `$1`.

```js
var string = `if ($exampl123 == 'test13')
            $example = 'test.testeg.hi';
        
            if ($exampl123 == 'test23')
            $example = 'test.testeg.hi';`


var regex = new RegExp (/(.*)test\.\w+\.hi/s);

console.log(string.replace(regex, "$1insert new text here"));
```